# How do I use Chip as a menu button in Joy UI?

Tags: joy-ui

I'm rewriting a Next.js application to use Joy UI.

Joy UI offers a `MenuButton` component to open a menu. It behaves identically like a `Button` in terms of style. I would like to use a different component by Joy UI, but keep the same behavior.

In my case, I need one menu button to be an `IconButton` and another menu button to be a `Chip`.

I believe I did find a way to do this in an elegant way a while ago, but I can't remember it anymore. I was unable to find anything about it in the [docs](https://mui.com/joy-ui/api/menu-button/). I tried changing the component by using the `component` prop, but it didn't achieve anything. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

`component` is the correct prop to use, but it's the other way around.

Instead of creating a `MenuButton` and passing `Chip` to it, create a `Chip` and pass `MenuButton` to it as `component`. Example:

```
<Chip
  component={MenuButton}>
  ...
</Chip>
```